# issues deploying a backend api on render

Tags: javascript, node.js

Got this error message:
May 14 04:27:30 PM error bson@5.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.20.1". Got "14.17.0"
May 14 04:27:30 PM error Found incompatible module.

checked my node version, and its way about the node engine required

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Render.com there could be two scenarios where the deployment get failed due to the .json file. of your backend root folder.

1. Existence of .lock.json file, affect the deployment by giving different versions of your dependencies...
2. Due to none existence of engine{} in the package.json.

by including

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=14 <15"
  }
```

in your package.json like

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "rahul4dev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {   
    "cors": "^2.8.5",    
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"   
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14 <15"
  }
}
```

you can give direction to render the specific engine for node version.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul Singh Thanks!
I had the same problem and solved with your assistance.